# Laravel - Using 'sleep' command in a cron job

Tags: php, laravel, server

**My Scenario**

I'm programatically creating servers and on server creation im firing a command, however it seems like the command is firing too early as the server isn't completely set up so the commands either fail, OR barely firing in time for server completion.

**My Question**
I want to know if it's safe to implement something like `sleep(120)` at the start of my script so it gives time for the server to finish setting up before running the command.

I only want this command to run once ever which is why i'm avoiding a database or any other more advance methods.

My script won't time out because I've read scripts ran via terminal don't timeout unless explicitly set.

Im not the most knowledgable at server side logic / best practices so it would be great to know any ins and outs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's 'safe', but it isn't smart IMO. Can't you just check if the server is provisioned and after that execute the commands?

Comment: @KoenHollander thanks for the reply, the server completion status returns 'true' when the server isn't fully complete. I think theres still some stuff happening in the background that doesn't allow commands to be executed however. We usually have to wait no longer than 5 minutes before actually being able to perform any actions.

Comment: for cases like this i like to use a lock file.

Comment: @spinsch Thanks for the answer but do you have any more information? The only lock file i know of is a composer.lock file and so far i've never come across an explanation of what it does explicitly.

Comment: you can create a file like `process.lock` before start creating server and remove if is done. but i found a another solution: add a cronjob with the flag `@reboot` instead of `* * * * *`. the cronjob will execute after reboot.

Comment: Thanks for this ill look into it more :)